# Unexpected behaviour with Data race detection by Xcode Thread sanitizer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, data-race

Here is a code snippet (from **Aubrey Kate** lesson about GCD) that will make the `Xcode` `Thread sanitizer` (A.K.A `TSan`) - detect a `Data race`:

```
import UIKit

final class MainViewController: UIViewController {
  var counter = 0
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "q")
    queue.async {
      for _ in 1 ... 10000 {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
        self.counter += 1
      }
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      for _ in 1 ... 10000 {
        self.counter += 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I comment out the `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)` - The `TSan` has no beef with me and will not crash the program.

My question is what essentially changed that the `TSan` is unable to detect the Data race??? why is it that the TSan need the `Thread.sleep` function to be able to locate the `data race` and without it, it's unable.

Comment: Today processors is fast enough to finish your first cycle before next async start with second, so no race over `counter`, but when you add `sleep` you make them overlapped, and sanitizer detects this. What you do is incorrect - `counter` should be either synchronised, - worse case, or updated on one queue, - correct case.

Comment: See the section on "Extended happens-before arc" in http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/35604.pdf. In particular: "In the pure happens-before mode, ThreadSanitizer will behave differently: if the race is real, the race may or may not be reported (depends on timing, this is why the pure happens-before mode is less predictable); if there is no race, the tool will be silent."

Comment: @Asperi I am studying the nature of data races. solving them is not the purpose. Vice versa